# The way to reaching God is to think about him lifelong?

Tags: gods

I am assuming that a person can max think about God but nothing else then how a person's thinking helps in getting moksha?

Whether it's worship or singing songs about God or constructing temples etc anything you take is maximum a thought in brain.

My question is how a thought takes someone near to god?

The purpose of life is to just think about God only at all times even while brushing teeth, bathing, eating, walking, sleeping etc.?

You may say we need to follow Dharma then for me that is also a thought generated in brain.

Just thinking about God will awake inner soul?

If it is just thinking then why someone need to do rituals? Is it just not enough to sit and think about God?

Comment: What you are confusing is - *god* as a creature or human being outside the realms of death. What god actually is - *the state of enlightenment*. If you keep thinking the same thing during brushing, bathing, or even disturbing your sleep then unfortunately you'll encounter OCD with your habits, and such *religious melancholy* is NOT normal. God is a state of mind that is not attached to anything in life (family, people, money, fame, status, etc) - this is simple.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many ways to reach GOD advocated by experienced Saints of all religions on Earth.

But, Easiest way is "NYAASATHILAKAM": that advocated Bounden duties from birth till death of a person.

Atleast a Janma is required to reach GOD because all beings born on Earth are bound to KARMA that may lead to either PUNYA or PAAPA.

It is impossible for a person to think GOD always. Disturbances may be created by competitors, enemies or suppressors or jealous persons or DEMON spirits in invaders etc. Further without earning one cant even have good food for stomach. Hence it is better to undergo stages of KARMA NYANA NYASA VIBHAAGA BHAKTHI PRAPATTI etc indicated by Sri VEDANTA DESIKAN/ by Divine Aachaaryas to reach GOD.

Comment: what is Nyana, Nyasa, Vibhaga etc? Pleass explain

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a clear understanding of what you mean by God and Moksha. You may be surprised to know that there are many meanings. And you may need to understand related concepts like Atma, Bramhan, Maya, Saguna/Nirguna etc.

I am assuming that you mean God - as what Hindus believe in like Ram/Krishna etc.

Just thinking about God is not enough to get Moksha. In Hindu context, to attain Moksha one needs to realize the true nature of Atma.

Thoughts control your actions. Hence it is important to control them. But just thinking about God is not going to lead to Moksha. Note that some of the saints do not ask for Moksha, they ask for eternal Bhakti of God! So, make sure if you really want Moksha.

Life has no purpose. Hence, many people follow some religion to establish a purpose. If you are Hindu religious person you can attain Moksha with or without involving God. If you are willing to read and educate yourself - read Samkhya philosophy. Not believing in God is not a bad thing in Hindu philosophy. Read about Gyan Marg vs Bhakti Marg.

Dharma is a very complex thing. For ordinary people it is recommended to just follow the path of great people, and do your duties.

Rituals are not going to give you Moksha.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my response to the answer. Krishna states in the Bhagavad Gita we cannot sacrifice work and be attached to inaction. Here is Bhagavad Gita 18.48 One should not abandon duties born of one’s nature, even if one sees defects in them, O son of Kunti. Indeed, all endeavors are veiled by some evil, as fire is by smoke. `https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org` As for Bhagavad Gita verse 2.47 You have a right to perform your prescribed duties, but you are not entitled to the fruits of your actions. Never consider yourself to be the cause of the results of your activities, nor be attached to inaction. Verse 18.11 of the Bhagavad Gita sums it up perfectly: For the embodied being, it is impossible to give up activities entirely. But those who relinquish the fruits of their actions are said to be truly renounced. So, in short, Ishvara isn't telling us thinking of god and not doing work is good. Rather we should try to live our life the way we choose, but with yogic practices and philosophy in mind and Ishvara is our guide to get to Brahman the eternal blissful truth.